# Deployments are failing with below MQ related errors in wildfly-19

Tags: java-8, ibm-mq, jboss7.x, wildfly-18

WE are migrating the application from Jboss & to wildfly 19 , deployments are failing with below MQ related errors . I've no clue about these errors complaining about the library file missing in the server . Can some one assist me on this.

WIldfly-19
Open JDK 8
MQ adapter : wmq.jmsra.rar

```
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001 ] [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$3] at:
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1244)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1085)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$1.run(LocalMQ.java:289)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise_inner(LocalMQ.java:281)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise(LocalMQ.java:244)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.<init>(LocalMQ.java:1330)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalServer.<init>(LocalServer.java:206)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:681)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:615)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:525)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent.getImplementationInfo(WMQComponent.java:191)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.getVersion(Trace.java:1994)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.setOn(Trace.java:558)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.msg.client.services.Trace.setStatus(Trace.java:101)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCATraceAdapter.enableTrace(JCATraceAdapter.java:237)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001 Object ClassLoader = ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar" from Service Module Loader
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001 CurrentThread ClassLoader = ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar" from Service Module Loader
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001  Cause:
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001 no mqjbnd in java.library.path [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError] at:
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:871)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1124)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1206)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1085)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$1.run(LocalMQ.java:289)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise_inner(LocalMQ.java:281)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise(LocalMQ.java:244)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.<init>(LocalMQ.java:1330)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalServer.<init>(LocalServer.java:206)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:681)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:615)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:525)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent.getImplementationInfo(WMQComponent.java:191)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001   com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.getVersion(Trace.java:1994)
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001 Object ClassLoader = null
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.840.00]  0001 CurrentThread ClassLoader = ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar" from Service Module Loader
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001  @48998340  c.i.m.jmqi.local.LocalServer(LocalMQ)                                    !  loadLib(Adapter)<throwIndex 2>,
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 [CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8598:
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 | Failed to load the WebSphere MQ native JNI library: 'mqjbnd'.
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 |
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 | The JVM attempted to load the platform native library 'mqjbnd',
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 | which was mapped to the filename: 'libmqjbnd.so'.
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 |
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 | When attempting to load the library, the JVM reported the error
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 | message:
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 | 'no mqjbnd in java.library.path'
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 |
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 | The JVM's bit-size is: '64'
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 |
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 | The library path which was used to locate this library was:
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 | '*** Configured java.library.path **********************************
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 |  "/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64"
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 |  "/usr/lib64"
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 |  "/lib64"
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 |  "/lib"
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 |  "/usr/lib"
  [23/03/21 15:53:13.841.00]  0001 | ********************************************************************'
```

Standalone-full-ha.xml

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
                <config-property name="connectionConcurrency">5</config-property>
                <config-property name="reconnectionRetryCount">5</config-property>
                <config-property name="logWriterEnabled">true</config-property>
                <config-property name="startupRetryCount">1</config-property>
                <config-property name="traceEnabled">true</config-property>
                <config-property name="traceLevel">3</config-property>
                <config-property name="maxConnections">25</config-property>
                <config-property name="reconnectionRetryInterval">300000</config-property>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:jboss/WMQConnectionFactory" pool-name="WMQConnectionFactory">
                        <config-property name="channel">CL.SC1023AC.TIMS</config-property>
                        <config-property name="hostName">sc1023ac.domain.com</config-property>
                        <config-property name="transportType">Client</config-property>
                        <config-property name="queueManager">SC1023AC</config-property>
                        <config-property name="port">49400</config-property>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
                <admin-objects>
                    <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/queue/PurchaseOrderExportQueue" pool-name="purchaseOrderExport">
                        <config-property name="baseQueueName">RQ.SCCO4234</config-property>
                    </admin-object>
```

Comment: Did you tired just change java version?

Comment: If you do not specify channel name and hostname (IP address) in your MQ connection parameters then the MQ client library assumes you are connecting to a local queue manager and uses 'bindings mode'.  For a bindings mode connection, as per the error message, it requires the 'libmqjbnd.so' shared library.

Comment: @AndreyRosa , No i haven't tried changing the underlying JDK 8.

Comment: @Roger, Those parameters are available in the standalone-full-ha.xml,

Comment: @Roger , MQ parameters as per my standalone-full-ha.xml are pasted here

Comment: @Vamsi because of the MQ Client library output, clearly it is not using the XML file.  I would review the instructions [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_latest/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q129260_.html)